# How to join two nested observables recurssively

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rxjs

I have an observable arrays, parents$ and children$ as defined below. I then have a class AttachChildren. The class has a method getChild$(parentId) that is used to get a relevant child for a given parent. Lastly, the method tesCollection() is used to populate the 'children' property of parent$ items. I have tried to use forkJoin to try and merge the two streams so that I can have the final data but so far have not been successfull. Blow are the relevant data and the class.
I am using typescript in node.js and rxjs version "^7.3.0".

```
const parents$ = of([
    {
        parentName: 'a',
        parentId: 0,
        children: []
    },
    {
        parentName: 'b',
        parentId: 1,
        children: []
    },
    {
        parentName: 'c',
        parentId: 2,
        children: []
    },
]);

const children$ = of([
    {
        parentId: 0,
        childName: 'a-a',
        childData: [
            {
                itemId: 0,
                itemName: 'd'
            },
            {
                itemId: 1,
                itemName: 'e'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        parentId: 2,
        childName: 'a-b',
        childData: [
            {
                itemId: 0,
                itemName: 'f'
            },
            {
                itemId: 1,
                itemName: 'g'
            }
        ]
    }
]);
```

I need the children to attach to parents via the relevant parentId property that is common to both parent$ and children$;
What I have tried is:

```
class AttachChildren{

   tesCollection() {
        parents$
            .pipe(
                mergeMap((m: Parent) => {
                    return m.map(parent => {
                        const child$ = this.getChild$(parent.parentId);
                        return forkJoin(
                            {
                                parent: of(parent),
                                child: child$
                            }
                        )
                    })
                })
            )
            .subscribe((p: any) => {
                console.log('subscribe/parents:', p);
            });

    }

    getChild$(parentId: number): Observable<Child> {
        return children$
            .pipe(
                mergeMap(c => c.map(child => child.parentId === parentId))
            )
    }
}
```

The result I am getting is as below:

```
subscribe/parents: Observable { _subscribe: [Function] }
subscribe/parents: Observable { _subscribe: [Function] }
subscribe/parents: Observable { _subscribe: [Function] }
```

How can I get to flatten this result?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you need to use so convoluted RxJS, in a very imperative way. I prefer to use it in a more functional way.

Here is a snippet that does associate parents and children. Even if this is not exactly the answer you are after, I hope it gives you a gist of how much simpler (to read and maintain) and less imperative the code could be.

```
forkJoin({
  parents: parents$,
  children: children$,
}).pipe(
  map(({children, parents}) => {
    const getChildrenOfParent = id => {
      return children.filter(child => child.parentId === id)
    }

    return parents.map(parent => ({
        ...parent,
        children: getChildrenOfParent(parent.parentId)
    }));
  })
).subscribe(console.log)
```

The output is:

[image]

I am using `forkJoin` here, as this is an Observable creator that will emit when all the streams have completed - which is perfectly fine for combining multiple `of` as in this example. You could also use `combineLatest` in real world, if you expect parents and children to arrive at random times. This will start emitting once every stream has emitted at least once.

Comment: Thanks user776686, your soluton works very well for me.  I must confess, these are among my first serious project trying to migrate from promises and async await to more functunal and reactive models.  Much as I have gone through Reactive Programming and RxJs, I am still migrating my mental thought process from imarative to functional programing model. In most books I have gone through, I expect this journey not to be very smooth. Much appreciated.

Comment: Completely understood! I am glad it works for you. I know that RxJS can be a big mental shift, as it was once for me. If I may advise you - every time you need to tackle a problem in RxJS, think declaratively, avoid invoking methods to get data on demand. Just set everything once, and wait for data :)

Comment: I am glad you understand my current challenges. Your advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first paragraph of my answer, as I read it now, might sound a bit harsh, scolding and patronizing (sorry about that), but I sort of assumed that you might have received a "requirement" to use a class, not willing to touch that. I am glad this is not the case, as class is completely unnecessary here. :)

Comment: Thanks. I took the sentiments objectively. Your advise is well noted and appreciated.

Comment: I represented the issue I had in the context of my node.js project implemented using typescript. For example the parents represented a module called 'module' and children represented a module called 'menu'. Each module has a menu.  I am currently separating concerns in classes.

Comment: I have written few things about RxJs which you may find interesting while starting your journey into Observables. This is about [typical patterns while using RxJs and http](https://betterprogramming.pub/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a) and this about a [typical use case with node using the file system](https://medium.com/free-code-camp/rxjs-and-node-8f4e0acebc7c)

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful given that my mind is still moulding itself around the concept of streams, functional programing and rxjs as a whole. I will read the articles and post one or two relevant question.